# How to do something periodically in ASP.NET/WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, wcf, web-services

First of all sorry of asking such a dumb question, I am quite a newbie in asp.net.

So, I am supposed to do something periodically, say I am owner of site heartpatients.com (hypothetically) and I want that for each of my site user who visits the site, a message to be shown after 2hrs "Take your pills". so, basically this is all my question, how am I supposed to show this message after every 2hr (or 4, 6 whatever time)after, also how can I customize time.
One more thing, say if I have this method in a WCF service, that shows this message, how can I call that service at a particular time, and that even configured by user (say someone is taking pills after 10hrs?) So how to call that service (that particular method in service) after the time specified by user passes periodically?

I hope I made my question quite clear.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to do this with a push notification to some kind of mobile device? I don't think it's realistic to do this in-browser while users have the web page up, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: It may be more appropriate to run the scheduling from the server side and then use something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) to *push* the message to the page.

Comment: @TimDog:  
Actually, what I really wanna do is allow the user to set a time duration, and after that much of duration (2hr, 4hr whatever) a mail (a sort of reminder) be send to user about their pills

Comment: @M.Babcock:  
Thanks for the insight. I could use comet, but push isn't the exact model I want, as I said in my previous comment, what I wanna do is allow user to set a time interval (2, 4, 6hr) and after that interval a mail be send to their email account, reminding them about taking their pills.  
Also, would it be possible that I create a event (send_mail) and then raise it after the time specified by user? In the event handler I could send the actual mail, is that possible?

Comment: @Razort4x - That differs greatly from my understanding of your question. The point of my previous comment was that this should not (possibly *could not*) be done client side in your application. When one of your users sets a specific time for them to take their pills (or it is determined another way) you should post back to the server telling it when to trigger the email being sent (note `SmtpClient` is good for this). "A message should be shown" has significantly different meaning than "I need to send an email when".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET generally isn't suited as a task scheduler.  The nature of the web is as a request/response system.  So a web application *should* just sit and wait for a request, generate a response, and be done.

For any kind of back-end scheduled task, I'd recommend either:

1. A [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx)
2. A console application scheduled to run (I think Windows comes with a task scheduler)

There are pros and cons either way.  For example, a Windows Service will run from boot time and has no console UI, and is generally very manageable from a server perspective.  While a console application is traditionally simpler to write and debug.

These can still share code from your web application.  If your business logic and data access and all that good stuff are in their own projects/assemblies then these other applications can use those assemblies just as well.  (Of course, if everything in your web application is UI-bound, that's another question entirely.)

What concerns me the most is... How do you plan to *show* this message to a user?  Is the user just sitting on your website for hours at a time and you need to remind them to take their meds?  Or do you plan to send an email or something?  Maybe the example you gave doesn't really explain what you're trying to do?  I'm not sure.

Running tasks in the background is one thing, but it seems to me that an entire half of your overall equation (displaying a message to the user) is sort of glazed over and not really thought through.

Comment: Yes - Windows does come with a task scheduler.

Comment: nice idea the Console application, and the task schedule.

Comment: @David
First thanks for your reply. Actually, what I really wanna do is allow the user to set a time duration, and after that much of duration (2hr, 4hr whatever) a mail (a sort of reminder) be send to user about their pills.

Comment: @David:  
Btw, is there a way, that I could create an event (sort of?) and then raise it at a particular time interval so that I can handle the event to do the work (sending mail at the time event is raised) in event handler? Is that possible?

Comment: @Razort4x: I see.  It's still going to be best to do the actual message sending part with a Windows Service or console application.  What your web application can do is have a form where the user selects the time (with whatever logic you want driving it), then that form would write records to a database table which basically record what to do and when (send an email, the recipient address, the message, the time to send it, etc.), and then the Windows Service just periodically (every minute?) polls that table for scheduled messages and sends them.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Quartz.Net:  http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

It enables you to schedule tasks to run using cron expressions:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron