# How to do something periodically in an IIS hosted app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

One requirement I have in the current project I'm working on is the following: we have a list of customers and each customer has a monthly fee, so the system must send the bills to the customers automatically based on the value it has to pay that month. The system sits on IIS and on the server is one Web API layer.

This would need the ability to do things periodically: each X th day of the month send this to the customer.

The problem is that as long as I've seem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884020/how-to-do-something-periodically-in-asp-net-wcf) this is not possible because ASP.NET will only answer to requests. The solutions presented there are solutions that run on the customer's computer which wouldn't work for me. So is there a way to do this with IIS? Where can I learn more abou that?

Comment: The two most common solutions are a custom windows service or leveraging Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a ping to one of your urls.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use IIS to do these sorts of tasks.  IIS is designed to respond to incoming requests.  Threads are managed by IIS itself, and the AppPool (i.e. AppDomain) could be recycled (or be suspended in Windows Server 2012 and later) at any time.  You could of course stop AppPool recycling etc., but it's still trying to make IIS feature do something it's not designed for.

You should write all of this background processing code to run as a Windows Service where you can control the process' lifetime.